# how to fire a HTTP POST from a html file?

Tags: html, http-post

I need to create a test html file so I can be able to test an API I created, but Im not a html coder at all.

So, i have the following:

```
POST /somepage.php HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 19

name=ruturajv&sex=m
```

I've tried putting that code on a file but browser doesnt fire it up.

What is the best and easy way to just write a simple HTML file which I just load into a browser and it automatically fires the POST method described above?

I appreciate all the help!

Comment: check ajax request GET&POST

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a simple form with fields called `name` and `sex` and the target `http(s)://example.com/somepage.php` with a `Submit` button.

Fill in `ruturajv` and `m`.

Click this button and the request will be sent.

```
<form action = "http://example.com/somepage.php" method = "post">
   <input type = "text" name = "name" value = "ruturajv">
   <input type = "text" name = "sex" value = "m">
   <p><input type = "submit"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Add `method="POST"` to the form as an attribute. If the method is not specified, it defaults to a GET request.

Answer (score -1):

easiest : use a

`<form>`

[form tag on MDN](http://www.taxhistory.org/thp/presreturns.nsf/) : the example should fit your bill.

If you wand something more sophisticated, lookup `XMLHTTPRequest`.